# Intel HAXM 6.0.4 not compatible with MacOS

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, haxm, android-sdk-manager

I have MacOS 10.11 El Capitain installed.
Today I got the notification that Intel HAXM 6.0.4 is available and the Android SDK Manager suggested me to remove Intel HAXM 6.0.3. I did it.

But now, I got the message that Intel HAXM 6.0.4 is not compatible with MacOS.

[image: Android SDK Manager Intel HAXM 6.0.4 not supported]

Is there a way to get the old version 6.0.3 back? Or is there any alternative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are already reported issues:

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223769
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223773

Here you would find and download HAXM 6.0.3 version: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Hope it will help

Comment: still not clear what is 6.0.4 and why its not available from Intel website

Comment: @serggl I added link to issue. Sorry but I'm not working in Intel or Google ;-)

Comment: for me also 6.0.3 is not working on Sierra :-( cannot install see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40703547/i-cannot-install-intel-haxm-on-macos-sierra

Answer (score 2):

As described in the [Issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=223769) it is possible to reinstall Intel HAXM 6.0.3 with the built-in Android Studio SDK Manager.

[image: Android Studio SDK Manager]

Answer (score 2):

You can also re-install from the command line (I'm assuming you have the 'android' executable in your path):

1. list all the available packages, including obsolete and outdated ones, with `android list sdk -a`
2. Look through the list for the "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer), revision 6.0.3" (it was #172 for me).
3. Install it with `android update sdk -a -u -t 172`

Explanation of parameters:

`-a` examines all packages

`-u` runs the command without the UI

`-t` tells the update command to only install packages that match the filter provided

`172` is the filter parameter. In this case, it is the package number from `android list sdk -a` that we want to install.

You can also pass `-n` to perform a dry-run if you want to verify your filter parameter(s).