# I cannot install Intel HAXM on macOS Sierra

Tags: android, intel, macos-sierra, haxm

I did download HAXM install package from Intel's page `https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/`.

However installation fails see log:

```
tokra@TOMASs-MBP:~/Downloads/haxm-macosx_v6_0_3$ sudo ./silent_install.sh -u
HAXM is not installed!
tokra@TOMASs-MBP:~/Downloads/haxm-macosx_v6_0_3$ sudo ./silent_install.sh
Silent installation failed, please see /private/tmp/haxm_silent_run.log for details!
tokra@TOMASs-MBP:~/Downloads/haxm-macosx_v6_0_3$ cat private/tmp/haxm_silent_run.log
/dev/disk2              GUID_partition_scheme
/dev/disk2s1            Apple_HFS                       /Volumes/com_intel_kext_haxm_disc
mpkg_file=/Volumes/com_intel_kext_haxm_disc//IntelHAXM_6.0.3.mpkg
ecx 7ffafbff
edx 2c100800
edx 2c100800
No emulator instance exist!
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/readline/lib/libreadline.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/bash
  Reason: image not found
installer: Error - A newer version of Intel HAXM is already installed on this computer. Installation will exit.
"disk2" unmounted.
"disk2" ejected.
Error: The installation-check script run failed !
*************** Silent installation failed ! ****************
```

Comment: have you followed: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I mentioned Intel's link, so yes i did follow instructions. however in cannot find `Installing standalone Intel® HAXM on Mac OS X` which they mention later.

Comment: oh, I just found `IntelHAXM_6.0.3.dmg` in the downloaded package :-) oh yes

Comment: Visit this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47230796/6465086
Worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

If installation over script fails try run DMG from package:
[image]

This solved my problem.

Comment: With version 7.3.2 of HAXM the certificate expired on June 26th, 2019.

Comment: The solution around the expired certificate is to download 7.5.1 (or a more recent) from https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases and install as shown above.