# Intel HAXM on macOS high sierra (10.13)

Tags: android, macos, emulation, intel

Is there any way of using Android emulator on High Sierra (10.13)?

When I run

```
./HAXM\ installation -u
```

It says:

```
HAXM silent installation only supports macOS from 10.8 to 10.12 !
```

Comment: Well, dont use silent installation?

Comment: @cricket_007 tried without silent installation (-u) and it didn't help as well.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The command line installation doesn't work and gives unsupported mac os version error, while the installation through IntelHAXM_6.2.1.mpkg works but kext is not loaded due to ["Approved Kernel Extension Loading" changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2459/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017658),

So you will need to allow the extensions from Intel and restart your mac,
then launch the emulator like from inside Android Studio,

To enable go to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: When I click on allow nothing happens. Even after a restart. What can I do?

Comment: I selected the allow button by pressing tab multiple times and then "clicked" the button with space. It works now, lol.

Comment: @Felix - Same for me. Nothing happens. Were you able to fix the issue?

Comment: @Felix - It turns out that it doesn't work via ScreenShare or SSH, so you need to be physically at the machine and use a Keyboard and Mouse - https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/issues/1017

Comment: @aeid, make sure that you installed HAXM through .mpkg file without issues

Comment: FWIW, double-click on .dmg to see the .mpkg

Comment: So when I clicked allow nothing happens, but the installation eventually succeeds. So yeah, just gotta wait a bit.

Comment: Thank you very much, after searching for hours this was my solution! I've installed HAXM on Mac but it didn't work, AVD still said that HAXM was missing. After installation you can validate with `kextstat | grep intel`. If it returns nothing then something is wrong you need to allow Intel in Security and Privacy.

Comment: I don't even have that warning with the "Allow" button there... :(

Comment: I just installed in Mojave and it appeared there, THANKS!

Answer (score 15):

I was able to install Intel HAXM drivers on my Mac using the instructions provided in [this post](http://web.archive.org/web/20170911023120/https://blog.celogeek.com/201708/672/android-studio-emulator-haxm-on-mac-os-high-serria-10-13/). There might be other (better) solutions to this, but I have successfully managed to start the emulator this way. Essentially you need to disable the security protection on `kext` before trying to install the HAXM drivers.

This command will only work on Recovery OS, which means that you need to restart your Mac and hold <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> until the Apple logo is displayed. Next, you need to go to `Utilities > Terminal` and run:

```
csrutil enable --without kext
```

Then restart your Mac and log in, go [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm) to download the latest Intel HAXM driver. Unzip if needed, edit the `silent_install.sh` file and search for the `10.12` OS version. You will find it on the line which should look like this

```
for v in 10.8 10.9 10.10 10.11 10.12
```

You need to add the `10.13` version after `10.12` (separated by space, just like the rest). Save the file and open a Terminal at this location. Run `./silent_install.sh` and that should be it. To be sure it works, you can also run `sudo kextload -bundle-id com.intel.kext.intelhaxm`.

Now your emulator should work.

In order to re-enable the `kext` security protection, you need to restart your Mac in Recovery OS, open a Terminal window and run `csrutil enable`.

Comment: Great work around. Any thoughts about the implications of such change ?
Why would Intel support "officially" up to 10.12 ?

Comment: @JalalEl-Shaer I don't think there are any side effects of installing the HAXM drivers this way. It seems that the Intel guys need to remove a [workaround](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62395878#comment18) for an old bug in the XNU kernel which was fixed in 10.13.

Comment: `csrutil enable --with kext` didnt work for me on 10.13. I had to run `csrutil clear` to reset SIP

Answer (score 12):

Intel Corporation just fixed it and released **HAXM** for **macOS Sierra** and **macOS *High* Sierra**, just download the ZIP and execute the **.dmg** file, then **restart** Android Studio. It worked for me, hope it works for you too.

*Intel Link for the download :* https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement-macosx

Comment: The kernel ext fails to install for me, end result is `/dev/kvm not found` when trying to install emulators.

Comment: This worked for me as well, however I needed to restart macOS after installing the .dmg.  Before restart I was getting HAX VM errors in the console when trying to launch the emulator.

Answer (score 8):

Use the new Hypervisor.Framework support on macOS.

Add this line in ***~/.android/advancedFeatures.ini*** (create this file if it doesn't exist already).

```
HVF = on
```

Issue answered here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62395878#comment7

That's worked for me.

Also you can be updated with Intel HAXM as they fixed this error.

Download HAXM latest version here **(Restart macOS Required)**:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement-macosx

Hope it help.

Comment: For some users the location for *advancedFeatures.ini* would be this `/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib`

Answer (score 3):

To verify that Intel HAXM is running, open a terminal window and execute the following command:

```
kextstat | grep intel
```

If Intel HAXM is operating correctly, the command will show a status message indicating that the kernel extension named `com.intel.kext.intelhaxm` is loaded.

**Try to stop and stat again HAXM.**, than verify it works correctly.

To stop Intel HAXM, use the following commands:

```
sudo kextunload -b com.intel.kext.intelhaxm
```

To start Intel HAXM, use the following commands:

```
sudo kextload -b com.intel.kext.intelhaxm
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google's 6.2.1's `silent_installer.sh` to properly install HAXM on High Sierra:

https://dl.google.com/android/repository/extras/intel/haxm-macosx_r6_2_1.zip

Otherwise use Android Studio's SDK Manager to download and install it for you:

This was not introduced until 6.2.1(Google Distribution only) which looks like a hotfix from the 6.2.0 version which would throw the following message:

```
HAXM silent installation only supports macOS from 10.8 to 10.12!
```

If you don't want to use HAXM, you can use the `Hypervisor.Framework` by ensuring you have installed `Android Emulator 26.1.3`

**Documentation**

> The emulator is now fully compatible with macOS 10.13 High Sierra through either Hypervisor.Framework or HAXM 6.2.0.

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator.html#26-1-3

Answer (score 1):

Try using Hypervisor.Framework as mentioned in this post.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62395878

Comment: What is that and how do you use it? I looked at that post and didn't get much from it, other then what you just stated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already installed the latest Intel HAXM Manager (v6.2.1) then re-install it and restart your computer. It will fix the emulator problem. You will be able to run emulators again. Here is the link:
https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm

Comment: have you read the question? because the question is about how to install haxm on high sierra which doesn't satisfy haxm max installable os which is Sierra. ![](https://i.imgur.com/aM7GlWe.png)

Comment: Yeap. It says it's not supported but re-install solved my issue. After updating to High Sierra, Android emulators stopped working. Then I re-installed the HAXM with the link above. Emulators started to work again.

Comment: I don't know how you did it but for me its just impossible to install and so for the author of this post as I understand. So we can't install it not that it fails working.

Answer (score 1):

Download this https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-end-user-license-agreement-macosx
and install .dmg then restart pc.This worked for me.

Comment: This is about Mac, not a PC.

Answer (score 1):

I had to go to `System Preferences > Security & Privacy`, click the unlock button, and a message will pop up asking to allow Intel to run. After that, HAXM ran on High Sierra.

Comment: Incomplete check answer from @Shaz

Comment: It's not incomplete, as this is exactly how I fixed my issue. You might not like my answer, but it fixed my problem.

Comment: What I meant to say is you left out the part where in addition to the Unlock button you need to click the `Allow` button as well.

Answer (score 1):

very specific case: if you keep android studio and sdk in separate partitions, and then you moved sdk to newly formatted partition, then in my case only uninstalling android studio and reinstalling it with new sdk is helped. sad story..